# Getting Ubuntu host's GUI on local machine when using X Window

Tags: linux, ssh-tunnel, x-windows, x11-forwarding, xquartz

I am tunneling X Window over ssh on my local OSX machine using XQuartz. 
Now the GUI of course looks different than what I would get when I start programs on ubuntu locally.
Is there a way to make my XQuartz on OS X draw the same GUI that Ubuntu offers?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you are looking for, but you could just draw the programs on the Ubuntu server and display them on the mac using [xpra](http://xpra.org/). There are other advantages to this approach: lower bandwidth consumption, no crash if the network drops (just re-connect).